# Hacer la media con las filas de una matriz

Tags: python, numpy, matriz

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# medidas obtenidas en el laboratorio multiplicadas por dos, ya que cada mm medido son dos milimetros en la realidad
tp=([0, -11, -11, -12, -11, -12, -13, -13.5, -14, -15, -15.5, -16, -17, -18, -17.5, -16.5, -17, -17.5, -16, -15, -14, -14],[0, -12, -13, -12, -12.5, -13.5, -13.5, -14, -13.5, -14, -13, -13, -14, -13.5, -14, -14, -14, -14.5, -14.5, -13, -13.5, -14],[0, -13, -13, -12, -12, -12, -12, -12, -12.5, -12.5, -12.5, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -13, -12, -12.5])
tp_2=np.array(tp)

# altura del segundo tubo
t=([0, -10, -9.5, -8, -7, -6, -5.5, -5, -4, -2, -1, 1, 3, 6, 10, 13, 16, 20, 24, 22, 22.5, 35],[0, -10, -9.5, -9, -8, -7, -6.5, -4.5, -3, -1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, 14, 18, 22, 24, 28, 31, 35],[0, -10, -10, -8, -7, -7, -6, -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 14, 16, 20, 23, 26, 29, 33, 36])
t_2=np.array(t)

# valores de las frecuencias
f=[0, 5, 7.5, 9.75, 12, 14.25, 16.5, 18.75, 21, 23.25, 25.5, 27.75, 30, 32.25, 34.5, 36.75, 39, 41, 43.5, 45.75, 48, 50]

# Se calcula la diferencia de altura entre tubos
da= [t_2-tp_2]
da_arreglo=np.array(da)
```

Necesito una función que me haga la media de cada fila de `da`. Para tener un vector con los datos promedio de cada experimento. En resumen, un comando que me haga la media de cada fila de `da`.

Si tuviera que implementar una función no habría problema, pero creo que tiene que haber una forma más sencilla como `np.mean()`, pero indicando que quiero seleccionar cada fila de esta matriz.

Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [`numpy.mean`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html#numpy-mean) tal como mencionas, usando su argumento `axis`. Por defecto calcula la media sobre el array aplanado (`axis=None`), pero puedes pasarle un entero o tupla de enteros indicando el eje o ejes sobre los que calcular la media. Si deseas calcular la media para cada una de las filas debes usar `axis=1` (y `axis=0` si desearas calcularla para cada columna):

```
da = t_2 - tp_2
dif_mean = da.mean(axis=1)  # np.mean(da, axis=1)
```

---

```
>>> dif_mean
array([19.13636364, 19.52272727, 19.81818182])
```

No se si tienes una razón para envolver la resta vectorizada en una lista (`da = [t_2-tp_2]`), en principio esos solo agrega una dimensión mas al array.